# Relationship creating extra nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is pretty basic, but I'm not sure why its happening:

CREATE (JFK:Airport)
CREATE (MIA:Airport)

CREATE (JFK)-[:ROUTE]->(MIA)

Instead of creating a relationship between JFK and MIA it actually creates two more nodes. I thought it would use the identifier of the node (JFK) and use that instance.

Comment: Also, are these all one Cypher statement or multiple?

Comment: Good question. If they were executed together I am sure that it would use the identifiers and only create 2 nodes, add 2 labels and create 1 relationship. EDIT: just tested and it is exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.  What if you did the following (changing variables to lowercase which is the most common practice)?

```
CREATE (jfk:Airport), (mia:Airport), (jfk)-[:ROUTE]->(mia)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian Underwood asked the question that stimulated my answer. You are executing the statements line by line. This creates 4 nodes, 2 labels and 1 relationship. Neo4j does not know what `JFK` or `MIA` relate to in the final create statement.

In detail:

```
CREATE (JFK:Airport)
```

This creates a node with the label `Airport` and no properties. `JFK` is the identifier used in this execution context only.

```
CREATE (MIA:Airport)
```

This creates another node with the label `Airport` and no properties. `MIA` is the identifier used in this execution context only.

```
CREATE (JFK)-[:ROUTE]->(MIA)
```

This creates two additional nodes with *no* labels and also creates a relationship between them.

If you execute them all together, Neo4j will use the `JFK` and `MIA` identifiers and only create the 2 nodes and 1 relationship.

```
CREATE (JFK:Airport) 
CREATE (MIA:Airport)
CREATE (JFK)-[:ROUTE]->(MIA)
```

This does what I think you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used two separate queries, the identifiers used in the first query are totally unknown in the second query.

Identifiers (for nodes and relationships) are temporary, and only meaningful within a single Cypher query -- they are never stored in the DB.

In fact, for completeness, you should know that an identifier may not even be meaningful throughout a single query, if that query contains [WITH statements](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html). For example, in the following query, you will end up with 3 nodes (2 `Airport` nodes, and 1 extra node without a label), because the `WITH` statement did not pass the `b` identifier forward:

```
CREATE (a:Airport {code:"JFK"}), (b:Airport {code:"MIA"})
WITH a
CREATE (a)-[:ROUTE]->(b);
```